# Algoritmo para gerar um diamante de caracteres

Tags: c, algoritmo

Estou tentando fazer um programa em C para gerar um diamante como exemplificado na imagem abaixo:

[image: Exemplo de resultado esperado]

Não consegui chegar a um algoritmo que gere os caracteres e os espaços necessários em cada linha.

Como seria uma forma razoável de resolver isso?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não vou dar o código, mas darei uma ideia sobre o algoritmo.

Primeiro, você precisará converter de letra para número, que vou chamar de `n`, de forma que `A` é 0, `B` é 1, etc. Coloquei o A como 0 e não como 1 porque acho que ficará mais fácil. Isso é importante para poder contar quantas linhas e quantos espaços serão necessários.

Para fazer isso, você usa a tabela ASCII, aonde `A` é o número 65. Portanto, para fazer esta conversão, basta subtrair 65 do caractere escolhido.

Depois, temos que desenhar o diamante, linha a linha. Vamos dividir a tarefa em dois, pois temos a metade superior e a metade inferior do diamante. Na metade superior temos `n` linhas, e portanto usar um laço `for` iterando de 0 até `n` é a melhor ideia.

Para cada linha, também temos duas metades (e portanto outros dois laços `for`). A metade da esquerda tem `n` caracteres e todos estes caracteres, com exceção de apenas um deles, serão espaços em branco. Para achar a exceção, supondo que você esteja usando como contador uma variável chamada `j`, você usaria `n-j`. O caractere a ser imprimido é o oposto da conversão para número feita a partir do `j`, então basta usar `j+65` nele.

Para a metade direita da linha, você itera `n-1` vezes de trás-para-frente o que fez na metade de esquerda.

Feita a metade superior do diamante, para fazer a metade inferior você usa uma estratégia similar a metade direita de cada linha, repete o que está no laço da metade superior, mas iterando `n-1` vezes de trás-para-frente.

Comment: Minha dificuldade é só em saber quantos espaços dar em cada linha, por exemplo: 
   A - 2 espaços A 2 espaços
  B  B - 1 espaços B 2 espaços B

Comment: @LuccasGabriel Na parte superior esquerda, antes da letra na i-ésima linha (contando a partir de 0) são `n-i` espaços antecedendo a letra. Se você iterar a parte direita da linha e a parte inferior do diamante de trás para frente, ele já irá refletir automaticamente.

Comment: Valeu Consegui seguindo sua logica depois de 1 hora kkkkkk

Comment: @LuccasGabriel, "... depois de 1 hora" - bem jogado: 1 hora que vais ver que valeu a pena!